# Is it possible to have an object serialized to a string representation instead of hyper-descriptive nested xml?

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class which describes a ratio of two numbers, it takes a string an can be turned into a decimal at will by the program. I'd like it to be serialized into a settings file so a user can enter the values at their leisure (ex 1/2, 4/5, 6/3, whatever) that gets serialized like this.

```
<ZoneInterface>
    <Ratio1>
        <Value>0</Value>
    </Ratio1>
    <Ratio2>
        <Value>2/3</Value>
    </Ratio2>
</ZoneInterface>
```

If at all possible, since the only thing that actually gets serialized is the Value string, I'd rather it get serialized like this

```
<ZoneInterface>
    <Ratio1>0</Ratio1>
    <Ratio2>2/3</Ratio2>
</ZoneInterface>
```

The class is pretty simple -- Is there any way I can add to it to force it to serialize/deserialize in a more succinct manor?

```
[Serializable]
public class Ratio
{
    private static Regex ValidationRegex = new Regex(@"^\d+/\d+$");
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return denominator == 1 ?
                $"{numerator}" :
                $"{numerator}/{denominator}";
        }
        set
        {
            if (ValidationRegex.IsMatch(value))
            {
                var args = value.Split('/');
                numerator = Int32.Parse(args[0]);
                denominator = Int32.Parse(args[1]);
            }
            else if (int.TryParse(value, out var result))
            {
                numerator = result;
                denominator = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException($"Unable to parse ratio {value}, must be of form \"[integer]/[integer]\"");
            }
            if (denominator == 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException($"Unable to parse ratio {value}, cannot divide by zero");
            }
        }
    }
    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public static implicit operator Ratio(string str)
    {
        return new Ratio() { Value = str };
    }

    public Decimal Decimal => ((decimal)numerator / (decimal)denominator);
}
```

Comment: Hi I think you can use the XmlArrayItemAttribute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/controlling-xml-serialization-using-attributes

Comment: Try a Json format instead. Check this link https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [XmlTextAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmltextattribute?view=netcore-3.1) on your Value property.  See below for minimal working example.  You can remove the attribute to check its behavior.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Ratio r = new Ratio { Value = "2/3" };
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Ratio));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, r);
            }
            Console.Write(sb);
            // prints as <Ratio>2/3</Ratio> (if you can ignore the xlmns:xsi clutter)
            // without [XmlText], would print as <Ratio><Value>2/3</Value></Ratio>
        }
    }
   
    public class Ratio
    {
        [XmlText]
        public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```